# Text Segmentation using Python package of wordsegment

Tags: python, text, nlp, text-segmentation, wordsegment

Folks,

I am using python library of [`wordsegment`](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/wordsegment/) by Grant Jenks for the past couple of hours. The library works fine for any incomplete words or separating combined words such as `e nd` **==>** `end` and `thisisacat` **==>** `this is a cat`.

I am working on the textual data which involves numbers as well and using this library on this textual data is having a reverse effect. The perfectly fine text of `increased $55 million or 23.8% for` converts to something very weird `increased 55millionor238 for` (after performing join operation on the retuned list). Note that this happens randomly (may or may not happen) for any part of the text which involves numbers.

- Have anybody worked with this library before?
- If yes, have you faced similar situation and found a workaround?
- If not, do you know of any other python library that does this trick for us?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are implementations in Ruby and Python at [Need help understanding this Python Viterbi algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447859/need-help-understanding-this-python-viterbi-algorithm/52764574#52764574).

The algorithm (and those implementations) are pretty straightforward, and copy & paste may be better than using a library because (in my experience) this problem almost always needs some customisation to fit the data at hand (i. e. language/specific topics/custom entities/date or currency formats).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, the `segment` function first runs `clean` which removes all non-alphanumeric character, it then searches for known unigrams and bigrams within the text clump and scores the words it finds based on the their frequency of occurrence in English.

```
'increased $55 million or 23.8% for'
```

becomes

```
'increased55millionor238for'
```

When searching for sub-terms, it finds `'increased'` and `'for'`, but the score for the unknown phrase `'55millionor238'` is better than the score for breaking it up for some reason.

It seems to do better with unknown text, especially smaller unknown text elements.  You could substitute out non-alphabetic character sequences, run it through `segment` and then substitute back in.

```
import re
from random import choices

CONS = 'bdghjklmpqvwxz'

def sub_map(s, mapping):
    out = s
    for k,v in mapping.items():
        out = out.replace(k,v)
    return out

mapping = {m.group():''.join(choices(cons, k=3)) for m 
           in re.finditer(r'[0-9\.,$%]+', s)}
revmap = {v:k for k,v in mapping.items()}
word_list = wordsegment.segment(sub_map(s, mapping))
word_list = [revmap.get(w,w) for w in word_list]
word_list
# returns:
['increased', '$55', 'million', 'or', '23.8%', 'for']
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try this. Anyway, I've also opened an issue on the `wordsegment`'s github issue page: https://github.com/grantjenks/python-wordsegment/issues/20