# Peter Norvig's word segmentation issue: how can I segment words with misspellings inside?

Tags: python, nlp, spell-checking, spelling

I'm trying to understand, how does Peter Norvig's spelling corrector work.

On his jupyter-notebook title [here](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/url/norvig.com/ipython/How%20to%20Do%20Things%20with%20Words.ipynb) he explains, how to segment a sequence of characters without spaces separating words. It works correct, when all the words in sequence are written correct:

```
>>> segment("deeplearning")
['deep', 'learning']
```

But when the word (or some words) in sequence is misspelled, it works incorrect:

```
>>> segment("deeplerning")
['deep', 'l', 'erning']
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to fix this and make the *segment()* function work with concatenated words with misspellings.

Does anybody have an idea how to deal with this problem?

Comment: I mean... this is a hard problem. Lots of research goes into this.

Comment: Do you know any articles about research on this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be achieved by Peter Norvig's [algorithm](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html) with minor changes. The trick is to add a space character to the alphabet and treat all bigrams separated by space character as a unique word.

Since big.txt doesn't contain `deep learning` bigram we will have to add a little bit more text to our dictionary. I will use [wikipedia library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wikipedia/) (`pip install wikipedia`) to get more text.

```
import re
import wikipedia as wiki
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
unigrams =  re.findall(r"\w+", open("big.txt").read().lower())
for deeplerning in wiki.search("Deep Learning"):
    try:
        page = wiki.page(deeplerning).content.lower()
        page = page.encode("ascii", errors="ignore")
        unigrams = unigrams + word_tokenize(page)
    except:
        break
```

I will create a new dictionary with all unigrams and bigrams:

```
fo = open("new_dict.txt", "w")
for u in unigrams:
    fo.write(u + "\n")
bigrams = list(nltk.bigrams(unigrams))
for b in bigrams:
    fo.write(" ".join(b)+ "\n")
fo.close()
```

Now just add a `space` character to the `letters` variable in `edits1` function, change `big.txt` to `new_dict.txt`  and change this function:

```
def words(text): return re.findall(r'\w+', text.lower())
```

to this:

```
def words(text): return text.split("\n")
```

and now `correction("deeplerning")` returns `'deep learning'`!

This trick will perform well if you need a spelling corrector for specific domain. If this domain is big you can try to add to your dictionary only most common unigrams / bigrams.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195010/how-can-i-split-multiple-joined-words) also may help.