# Regex to capitalize first letter of every word

Tags: regex, notepad++, notepad

Hello everyone i have some texts that looks like this

- `jameskach` --> `JamesKach`
- `firefighter11` --> `FireFighter11`
- `attackontitan` --> `AttackOnTitan`
- `lazyperson` --> `LazyPerson`

Not all the texts are the same, i was just showing some examples, any help is appreciated

Comment: (\w+) replace with \u$0                      this one only does the first letter of the word, so like  it turns attackontitan to Attackontitan and i need it to be AttackOnTitan

Comment: How could you know what letter must be uppercased in `attackontitan`? I don't think it is possibel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regex to match & group first character :

```
^(.)
```

What to replace with :

```
\U\1
```

(the `\1` means the first matching group.)

Comment: This works great, but doesnt capitalize every first letter in the sentence, so like attackontitan turns into Attackontitan but i need to turn into AttackOnTitan

Comment: Well that case is not possible. You would need to include a whole full dictionary into the regex which is *absolutely not* good.

Comment: Also, from a dictionary : `Words are usually separated by spaces in writing, and are distinguished phonologically, as by accent, in many languages.` So you should find your answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195010/how-can-i-split-multiple-joined-words